# How do I download 1.6.1 on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have downloaded everything I need and forced a download, but I dont know how to get 1.6.1 on my minecraft account? Please Help!

Comment: What do you mean by "get it on your account"? You run the launcher that you downloaded, and sign in there. No need to add the new version to your account.

Comment: I understand what he did. You have to get the new launcher, the old one wont work no matter how much you 'force update'. Pay attention to what the bulletin says dude.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the new launcher.
[Windows](http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.exe)
[Mac OSX](http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.dmg)
[Linux/Other](http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar)
To install the launcher, simply download and run the program.

### Quick tips about the launcher

- ***You do not need to re-purchase Minecraft to use the new game launcher.***
- The new launcher is required in order to play Minecraft version 1.6 and any future updates. The old launcher will not update past version 1.5.2.
- The program is self-updating, so we won't require another manual download in the future.
- The interface is still in an early version, and will continue to receive updates to improve its look.
- You can still play Minecraft version 1.5.2 using the old launcher, which you can download from [minecraft.net/download](http://minecraft.net/download)
- Support for multiple Minecraft usernames per Mojang account is included in the launcher, but is not yet enabled in Mojang accounts.
- You will always be able to access singleplayer content while offline. However, in the new launcher, you must actually be offline, or else the launcher will continue to try to contact the login servers.

Some of the new features include: streamlined downloading of Minecraft updates, increased password security, the ability to switch between game versions, the use of updated game code libraries for increased performance and stability, and it paves the way for the future [plugin APIs](http://www.gamespot.com/minecraft/videos/the-future-of-mod-api-minecon-2012-6400552/).
If you've saved your login information on the old launcher, and cannot recall your password, visit [our password change article](http://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/329524), or [contact customer support](http://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new). Issues with the launcher can be reported on the [bug tracker](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MCL).
http://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1163345-new-minecraft-launcher